# SQL Injection issue. Using SQLParser for executing the query

Tags: java, sql

Recently we did Vulnerability scan to our project and we found SQL Injection issue.

In my project we are using code like:

```
SQLParser x = new SQLParser(query);
SelectStatement y = x.parseQuery();
List<ParseNode> groupByNode = y.getGroupBy();
```

For the above code it saying like SQL Injection as we are passing the query directly, but we are executing the query via `SQLParser` and doing operation using  `org.apache.phoenix.parse.SelectStatement`.

Kindly give a suggestion to this.

Comment: I don't know that API (SQLParser) but using a `PreparedStatement` when you have parameter to pass to the query is always safer. Note that if that API is assuring the Injection free execution, it might be a simple false positive issue because of the API used.

Comment: How you create query?

Comment: Thanks for quick reply. we are using this 
 API for of org.apache.phoenix.parse.SQLParser. I agree that we can use PreparedStatement but this is an old code written from my seniors a long back and lots business operation are also been carried on in this. So kindly can you please give some suggestion with solution. the scan report have mentioned as SQL injection can happen at 'y.getGroupBy()' this point .

Comment: The **only** way to be safe against SQL injenction is to use a `PreparedStatement` - so you will have to bite the bullet and refactor the code (and those "seniors" don't seem to be that experienced after all if they didn't use PreparedStatements from the beginning)

Comment: Thank you again for quick reply i just check with my team regarding Y we used the org.apache.phoenix.parse.SQLParser instead of prepare statement. The reason behind it is we take the query from property file and we convert that into the SQLParser and then to SelectStatement  to make POJO kind object and we exectute the query in Elastic search..Can please suggest how to handle this issue.